# Custom panning using ArcGIS Engine

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, c#, api

Due to some constraints, that I will not go into, I have found myself needing to implement custom panning in my application.

The ArcGIS API reference suggests using the following methods:

```
IScreenDisplay2.PanStart(IPoint start)    // Starts a pan
IScreenDisplay2.PanMoveTo(IPoint moveTo)  // Moves to a point
IScreenDisplay2.PanEnd()                  // Ends the pan
```

Each of these methods is called in the following event handlers (respectively):

```
IMapControl4.OnMouseDown     // Call PanStart()
IMapControl4.OnMouseMove     // Call PanMoveTo()
IMapControl4.OnMouseUp       // Call PanEnd()
```

So all of that works fine, the events are handled, the panning starts, everyone is happy.

-but-

Where the screen actually pans is not where I have dragged my cursor.  The map slides around in a somewhat deterministic pattern, but I can't seem to figure out how to compensate for what the API is doing.  I have been unable to find any enlightening documentation.

Does anyone have experience with this part of the API?  Sample code or documentation would be great!

Comment: Did you try setting up a debug statement to print out [IDisplayTransformation.DeviceFrame](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DeviceFrame_Property/001w000000t0000000/) as the map completes each pan? In the past, I have noticed under certain conditions the device frame size gets changed to an inappropriate value.

Comment: @Kirk - The `DeviceFrame` does not change at all when panning.  That is to be expected though, correct?  The device frame is just the size of the frame in device coordinates (pixels)

Comment: Correct, it should not change.  Did you try listening to [ITransformEvents.VisibleBoundsUpdated](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/VisibleBoundsUpdated_Event/001w000003n0000000/) on the displaytransformation instance?  Maybe it is getting called twice?  Also, did you try calling [TrackPan](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/TrackPan_Method/001w000002z0000000/) instead?

Comment: @Kirk No luck with `VisibleBoundsUpdated` calling twice.  I would use `TrackPan()` but I need to continue to handle mouse events while panning and they are supressed during a `TrackPan`

Comment: Can you post the code in the event handlers. Does the panning terminate OnMouseUp and just ends up in an unexpected location? Have you tried creating a point from the X,Y of OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp?  Do they correspond with where panning starts and ends.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this @ version 10 SP 1 but it should work on any version.

```
public class PanTool extends BaseCommand implements ITool {
private HookHelper hookHelper = null;
private IScreenDisplay display;

public PanTool()    {
    this.category = "Text";
    this.caption = "Text";
    this.message = "Text";
    this.toolTip = "Text";
    this.name = "Text";
    this.bitmapPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/cmdbitmaps/your_icon.bmp";
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Object hook)   {
    if (hook == null)
        return;
    try {
        hookHelper = new HookHelper();
        hookHelper.setHookByRef(hook);
    } catch (Exception e)   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick()   {
    try {
        MapControl map = (MapControl) ((ToolbarControl) hookHelper.getHook()).getBuddy();
        map.setCurrentToolByRef(this);
    } catch (Exception e)   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMouseDown(int button, int shift, int x, int y) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    if(button == 1) {
        MapControl map = (MapControl) ((ToolbarControl) hookHelper.getHook()).getBuddy();
        display = map.getActiveView().getScreenDisplay();

        display.panStart(display.getDisplayTransformation().toMapPoint(x, y));
    }
}

@Override
public void onMouseUp(int button, int shift, int x, int y) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    if(button == 1 && display != null)  {
        display.panStop();
        MapControl map = (MapControl) ((ToolbarControl) hookHelper.getHook()).getBuddy();

        map.getActiveView().refresh();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMouseMove(int button, int shift, int x, int y) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    if(button == 1 && display != null)  {
        display.panMoveTo(display.getDisplayTransformation().toMapPoint(x, y));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextMenu(int x, int y) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean deactivate() throws IOException, AutomationException {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getCursor() throws IOException, AutomationException {
    return esriSystemMouseCursor.esriSystemMouseCursorHand;
}

@Override
public void onDblClick() throws IOException, AutomationException {

}

@Override
public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, int shift) throws IOException, AutomationException {

}

@Override
public void onKeyUp(int arg0, int arg1) throws IOException, AutomationException {

}

@Override
public void refresh(int arg0) throws IOException, AutomationException {

}
```

}
}